# how to join two dataframe and align on a specific column like this?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do some work by joining two dataframe and aligning on a specific column like this:

dataframe left like:

```
dict1={'abstract': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'A3', 3: 'B1', 4: 'B2', 5: 'B3', 6: 'B4', 7: 'C1', 8: 'C2'}, 
       'name': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'C', 8: 'C'}}

left=pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

dataframe right like:

```
dict2={'abstract': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'B1', 3: 'B2', 4: 'B3', 5: 'C1', 6: 'C2', 7: 'C3'}, 
       'name': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'C', 6: 'C', 7: 'C'}}

right=pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

And I want to get a combined dataframe like this:

```
dict3={'name': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'C', 8: 'C', 9: 'C'}, 
       'abstract_right': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: nan, 3: 'B1', 4: 'B2', 5: 'B3', 6: nan, 7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: 'C3'}, 
       'abstract_left': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'A3', 3: 'B1', 4: 'B2', 5: 'B3', 6: 'B4', 7: 'C1', 8: 'C2', 9: nan}}

combined=pd.DataFrame(dict3)
```

How to do it with Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is less than a join but more than a concatenation since they have to be matched by `name`. You can create an `id` column to help you merge and align the rows:

```
left['id'] = left.groupby('name').cumcount()
right['id'] = right.groupby('name').cumcount()
left.merge(right, on=['id', 'name'], how='outer', suffixes=['_left', '_right']).drop('id', axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not aware of help from additional information ... just as when dealing with geometrical problems

Answer (score 3):

You can merge with additional information where the value cam from and add the
left and right columns later:

```
res = pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', indicator=True)
res['abstract_left'] = res.abstract[res._merge != 'right_only']
res['abstract_right'] = res.abstract[res._merge != 'left_only']
res.drop(['abstract', '_merge'], axis=1)
```

[image]

#### In Steps

Do an outer join:

```
res = pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', indicator=True)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Now, you add your two columns based on the values in `_merged`:

```
res['abstract_left'] = res.abstract[res._merge != 'right_only']
res['abstract_right'] = res.abstract[res._merge != 'left_only']
```

[image]

and remove the unwanted columns:

```
res.drop(['abstract', '_merge'], axis=1)
```

for the final result.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the merge function but I added "on='name'" and got a 24*4 dataframe.

Comment: Per default it is on all columns with the same name in both dataframes. So here `on=['name', 'abstract']`, because both dataframes have these two columns.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function

```
left_df.merge(right_df, how='outer', indicator=True)
```